# PHP Mysql syntax using MD5 and NOW functions

Tags: php, mysqli

Consider this:

`$query = 'UPDATE ' . $table . 'SET optin_date = NOW() WHERE MD5(email_address) = ' . $email;`

And I get this error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= NOW() WHERE MD5(email_address) = c5dfd29d956b52c1ffa00ce4a06ab' at line 1`

What I want is to store the **current timestamp** to the `optin_date` column using `NOW()` function as its value (I'm not sure on how it works), only if the hashed email from the query string matches the hashed email from the database using `MD5()` from mysql. I already have a column having `TIMESTAMP` type and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` default.

Also, I need to send a mail for confirmation using the email address. Is this possible? What's a better way of doing this?:

`$recipient = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE MD5(email_address) = ' . $email;`

Please help me on the syntax and if there's an elegant way of coding 'Email Confirm Subscriptions" (At least the function handling hashed emails) that you might want to share, please feel free. Thanks.

Comment: use a space befor SET and $email has to be a string for mysql e.g. `MD5(email_address) = "'.$email.'"`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these `` around table names and field names, also you have a missing SPACE after $table

```
$query = 'UPDATE `' . $table . '` SET `optin_date` = NOW() WHERE MD5(`email_address`) = ' . $email;
```

you should probably also use .mysql_real_escape_string($email) instead of just .$email at the end there - Security risk

```
$query = 'UPDATE `' . $table . '` SET `optin_date` = NOW() WHERE MD5(`email_address`) = ' . mysql_real_escape_string($email);
```

Unless of course (as it seems) your $email would be a md5 hash

Answer (score 0):

you have syntex error at in sql query 
write this query

```
$query = "Update '".$table."' SET option_date = NOW() WHERE email_address ='".md5($email)."' ";
```

Answer (score -1):

try with this:

```
$query = "UPDATE " . $table . "SET optin_date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
          WHERE MD5(email_address) = '" . $email . "'";
```

Comment: Seems someone just gave minus to all answers.